# shell command does not work in excel 2010 vba in win 7

Tags: excel, shell, vba, pdf, acrobat

Recently upgraded from Win XP to Win 7 with Adobe Acrobat 10 Standard.  I need the correct command to print a pdf file using Excel 2010 VBA.  Was using the following code that worked.

```
'acrobat executable
pdfApp="C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat 10.0\Acrobat\AcroRd32.exe" 

'remote server file
f(doctyp)="\\sorl0008\groups\ACROBAT_DATA\PS\out\600374_e.pdf" 

'prints adobe pdf (ORIGINAL CODE THAT WORKED)
Shell pdfApp & " /t " & Chr(34) & f(doctyp) & Chr(34), vbNormalFocus
```

When I run this now, once the shell command is executed the screen sort of flashes briefly and absolutely nothing happens.  Why is this happening?  Is it something with Adobe Acrobat 10?  I can successfully open the file using the following code, but most times I don't want to view the file, just send to default printer and move on.
v = Shell(pdfApp, vbNormalFocus) 'open adobe
ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink f(doctyp) 'open file in adobe

Even if I open the file and then try to print I get the same result of a quick screen flash and nothing.  I turned off Data Execution Prevention in Windows 7 and it still doesn't work.  Any ideas to what is wrong?

Comment: `Even if I open the file and then try to print I get the same result of a quick screen flash and nothing.` You mean after manually opening the file? If yes, then maybe there is a problem with your printer settings?

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked for me on 64-bit Win 7, except the path to Adobe reader is different:

```
'acrobat executable
'pdfApp = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat 10.0\Acrobat\AcroRd32.exe"
pdfApp = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 10.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe"

'remote server file
'f(doctyp) = "\\sorl0008\groups\ACROBAT_DATA\PS\out\600374_e.pdf"
doc = "some unc path"

'prints adobe pdf (ORIGINAL CODE THAT WORKED)
Shell pdfApp & " /t " & Chr(34) & doc & Chr(34), vbNormalFocus
```